# Is memory allocated for a character array given as actual parameter in a function call?

Tags: c++, c, function, arrays

I just want to know whether a character array given as actual parameter during function call is getting stored in some memory.
Ex:

```
void printIt(char* ptr) {
......
}
```

This function is called as follows:

```
printIt("hallo");
```

This works fine. But if we pass an integer and receive it as int* it won't work, as we are not allocating memory for it. So is the compiler automatically allocating memory for a character array passed as argument?

Comment: You aren't passing an array, you're passing a pointer to the first element. Arrays can't be passed by value.

Comment: Note that `"hallo"` is a constant string; any attempt to modify it leads to undefined behaviour.  Ideally, the function should be defined as `void printIt(const char *ptr) { … }` or equivalent.

Comment: Well **somewhere** it **must** have **some** memory allocated to it. Ya know, computers store data in… **memory.** So yes, 6 bytes (`h`, `a`, `l`, `l`, `o` and the terminaing NUL) are allocated for the string literal. This is **completely unrelated** to the fact that arrays decay into pointers when passed to a function. A string literal is an array. A single `int` is not an array. Hence, passing a string literal when a pointer-to-`char` is expected will work, and passing an `int` when an `int *` is expected won't work.

Comment: For windows (.exe) files.. That string is stored in the `.data` section. Not sure if it requires a "memory allocation". I think only the address of it is passed to the function.

Comment: It definitely requires a memory allocation, else there wont be an address to pass. It may be stored in the read only data section or on the stack for that function....not sure which is actually used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to reflect input from comments:

Are you asking where in memory it is held? The string "hallo" is being held as a string literal in read only memory. So a pointer must be passed (which is held in the local stack space for your printit() method) so that the method can find the string. As other people have pointed out the pointer refers to the first letter of the string, which is stored as an array of characters. The reason you do not pass a pointer for an int is because you pass the actual value which is then stored locally on stack.

Comment: Only the pointer to that string is pushed to the stack. The string itself resides in read only memory.

Comment: I can understand that the compiler is storing it in the read only section, like the other string literals. But why then we cant pass a integer
    printIt(&10);
Why doesn't the compiler store the integer as a constant in memory and pass its address.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out glglgl I think that is an important distinction. Jose I think it is just a case that the int IS passed literally as a value and held on the stack for your printit() method as a local variable, whereas as glglgl pointed out the string is held itself in the readonly memory and therefore a pointer must be passed. This comes down to the architecture of the language and I guess these decisions have been made relating to performance. It is certainly an interesting topic though.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
printIt("hallo");
```

you're sending the *base address* of the string literal "hello" to `printIt()` function and you're accepting the same in `char* ptr`. `ptr` points to the base address of `"hallo"`. There is no separate memory *allocated* as such.

In this same logic, passing an `int` and receiving it into `int *` wont work. You need to pass `&<some int>`.

<sup>Note: `char * ptr` variable itself is having local scope in the function `printIt()`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the string to the function, the pointer variable ptr will be pointing to `h` because it is the starting position of the string, and it will print the NULL character.
4 bytes will be allocated for ptr in 32 bit system, so it will get the string.